# ogr2ogr FAILURE: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'ùnlt'!

Tags: ogr2ogr

I am getting the following error message with ogr2ogr while try to convert into MySQL.  I have tried PGeo,Shapefile and FileGDB.

**FAILURE: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'ùnlt'!**

My environment is Window10 running under Paralles11 on Mac OS X El Capitan.
I have tried in FWtools and latest OSGeo4W Shell.  Has anyone seen this error before and know how to resolve it?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and update your question with your code so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Remove any special characters such as ù and try again

Comment: ogr2ogr -f "MySql" MySql:"<mysql_connection>" "<filepath>\<filename>.gdb" FIRE_DISTRICTS -nlt GEOMETRY -lco ENGINE=MyISAM -lco PRECISION=false -overwrite

Comment: @underdark There are actually no special characters in the data.                     I was later able to get a successful conversion by removing "-nlt GEOMETRY" and running the shell as administrator **curse you WIN10** and subsequent reloads with "-nlt GEOMETRY" have worked.